# Bias of a function of the avarage

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

$\overline{x}$ is an unbiased estimator of the exact average.

Now, we let's imagine that we want to estimate some function of the average $f(\langle x \rangle)\equiv f(X)$.

My first guess was $\overline{f(x)}=\frac{1}{N}\sum f(x_i)$. However, when you analyse the bias one obtains $\langle\overline{f(x)}\rangle-f(X)=\int P(x)(f(x)-f(X))dx=f'(X)\int P(x)(x-X)dx+\frac{1}{2}f''(X)\int P(x)(x-X)^2dx+...=\frac{1}{2}f''(X)(\langle x^2 \rangle - \langle x \rangle^2)=\frac{1}{2}f''(X)\sigma^2$

We get that the estimator is of order unity, so if you increase $N$, the bias remains the same.

I want a best estimator and its proof. I know it's $f(\overline{x})$, however I don't follow the proof (it seemes so straight forward)

The document that I'm following is http://young.physics.ucsc.edu/jackboot.pdf

Comment: Where do you got stuck?

Comment: As far as I understand it must follow like $\langle f(\overline{x})\rangle-f(X)=\int P(x)(f(\overline{x})-f(X))d\overline{x}=f'(X)\int P(x)(\overline{x}-X)d\overline{x}+\frac{1}{2}f''(X)\int P(x)(\overline{x}-X)^2d\overline{x}+...$ However, $\overline{x}=X$, so it's zero and there's no bias and the solution in the document is $\frac{1}{2N}f''(X)\sigma^2$

Comment: Futhermore, I can't use that $\int xP(x)dx=X$ in order to cancel out the first term